# Link node 1 to node 2 and create list

Tags: views, nodes

I basically have a content type of companies and another of events. I would like to have a page with a select list of all companies and a select list of all events so that the user can choose what company is attending what event. This will need to allow multiple combinations.

**Example:** Company 1 will be at Event 1 and Event 2.

There will need to be list of all companies attending the selected event.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using a combination of [Editable Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/editableviews) and [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference).

You will need to create an entity reference field on one of the content types that points to the other. Then create a view of that content type.

Using editable views you can have a select list to add an entity reference on the company node to the event node. If you set up the entity reference field to allow multiple values, you will be able to have one company attending multiple events.

You can also create a view that shows all entities that reference the the event in order to show a list of all companies who will be attending an event.

Comment: Thanks. How can I remove the companies that have already been selected / linked to the event, so that they cant be selected more than once. Kind of like a check list of who's coming, but would need to be a dropdown list

Comment: I don't think this would be possible on company side, since you won't know which event you are talking about. If you went into the event view, then you could add a filter to not show companies that are referencing the current event.